# No valid hardware interface element found in joint

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following error trying to load simulation interface for gazebo ros . This worked in hydro but after moving to ubuntu 14 - indigo I now get these errors. I can not see any thing that has changed in the documentation for this feature. It there a indigo-devel lib I need? I pull all software from ubuntu software center. I also compiled gazebo-ros-pkgs from source from indigo-devel.

```
[ERROR] [1405708119.053840656]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'joint1'.
[ERROR] [1405708119.053997707]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'tran1'.
[ERROR] [1405708119.054095180]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'joint2'.
[ERROR] [1405708119.054185473]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'tran2'.
[ INFO] [1405708119.161913723]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[ERROR] [1405708120.087262628, 0.468000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint1_position_controller.
Could not find resource 'joint1' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1405708120.087374119, 0.468000000]: Initializing controller 'joint1_position_controller' failed
[ERROR] [1405708121.093701156, 1.280000000]: Exception thrown while initializing controller joint2_position_controller.
Could not find resource 'joint2' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1405708121.093770162, 1.281000000]: Initializing controller 'joint2_position_controller' failed

    

In Gazebo:

    <joint name='joint2' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0.03 0 1.5707 1.5707</pose>
        <child>right_wheel</child>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-1e+16</lower>
            <upper>1e+16</upper>
          </limit>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <plugin name='ros_control' filename='libgazebo_ros_control.so'>
        <robotNamespace>/rrbot</robotNamespace>
        <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
      </plugin>
   

In URDL .xmacro

  <transmission name="tran2">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint2"/>
    <actuator name="motor2">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      <motorTorqueConstant>10</motorTorqueConstant>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>



In Yaml

rrbot:
  # Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 10

  # Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
  joint1_position_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: joint1
    pid: {p: 40, i: 1, d: .1, i_clamp: 1}
  joint2_position_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: joint2
    pid: {p: 40, i: 1, d: .1, i_clamp: 1}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186681/no-valid-hardware-interface-element-found-in-joint/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-15**:
I can't help you with your actual problem, but might I suggest you change your question title to something a little more descriptive? Your current title is rather vague.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-15**:
thank you...it was indeed vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I met the same problem as you. Finally I find out the reason is that in this version of ros_control/transmission_interface/transimission_parser.cpp , the parser will check if there are   tags in both  section and  section. But in rrbot and other gazebo example, only  has  tag. Therefore this error occurs.

By adding  tags to  section, this error disappears. For example, in rrbot.xacro, change

```
<joint name="joint1"/>
```

as:

```
  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
  </transmission>
```

---

Originally posted by [lockandfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/18746/lockandfire/) with karma: 276 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-07-20**:
This seems to work..thanks.. , not sure if this is a gazebo or ros issue. I can not find documentation of how or why this changed. Any thoughts on this?

**Comment by [lockandfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/18746/lockandfire/) on 2014-07-22**:
It seems to be a ros issue with indigo because this change is found in indigo version of ros_control pkg. I don't know why ...

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2014-08-02**:
I have posted an issue in the ros_control bug tracker: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues/177

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2014-08-02**:
Duplicate with: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6654/gazeboos-x-109-no-valid-hardware-interface-element/

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2015-01-10**:
Fixed by @Kei Okada https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/pull/4